# Wpf Windows Store Apps Checkbox cannot resize

Tags: wpf, checkbox, windows-store-apps

I simply cannot make check box size smaller than 168px in Windows Store App - XAML file.
Please see SS below.

What can I do? Sometimes...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the `CheckBox` has a default `MinWidth` value of `168`.

Just add `MinWidth="0"` to the `CheckBox`'s xaml and it will resize properly.

```
<CheckBox MinWidth="0" ... />
```

How I found it out -

Open your xaml file in Blend. Select the `CheckBox` and then expand the **Layout** section in *Properties panel*.

You will see **168** next to the **MinWidth** field.

[image]